# How to prove the ring $R_J$ is Noetherian without use the theorem of I. S. Cohen?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, finitely-generated

First define $R:=k\left[{\{X_i\}}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\right]$ where $k$ is a field (it could be an integral domain as $\mathbb{Z}$ too for example). This ring is an integral domain and it is not Noetherian. The second thing to do is define the primes ideals that I want there exist in the new ring. For this I define ${J_1}:={I_1}:={\langle X_1 \rangle}_R$, ${\forall i>2}:\;I_{\{2,i\}}:={\langle X_2,X_i \rangle}_R$, $J_2 := \underset{i>2}{\bigcup}{I_{\{2,i\}}}$, and so, ${I_{\{{n,i_{n−1},i_{n−2}, \ldots, i_1}\}}}:={\langle{X_n, X_{i_{n-1}}, X_{i_{n-2}}, \ldots, X_{i_1}} \rangle}_R$ where $i_1 > i_2 > \ldots > i_{n−1} > n$ are naturals, and $J_n:=\underset{i_1 > i_2 > \dots > i_{n−1} > n}{\bigcup}I_{\{n,i_{n−1},i_{n−2},\ldots,i_1\}}$. Then I define $J:=\underset{k \in \mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}{J_k}$. All the ideals defined are primes, then $J$ is union of primes ideals of $R$, which are all of them finitely many generated as $R$-mod. By the theorem of I. S. Cohen is easy seeing that the localization $R_J$ is Noetherian (and his Krull dimension is infinite). But I want prove the Noetherianity of $R_J$ without the theorem of I. S. Cohen. We can use for example that each ascending chain has a finite length in a localization of $R_J$ on any $I\in J$ is equivalent to Noetherianity of $R_J$, but I do not know how to proceed. Someone has an idea?

Comment: This is Nagata's example of a Noetherian ring of infinite dimension. You can find elementary proofs by googling ...

Comment: No, this isn't the same example. In the Nagata's example, the primes ideals on which he localizes the ring are sets of primes with intersection $(0)$, the elements in his example are in a finitely many maximal ideals, but in this case it is not posible using the same argument because infinite many elements are in infinite many different maximal ideals. Then, his lemma of the appendix of "Local Rings" is no tvalid in this case.

Comment: For example, ${\langle X_{100},X_{1000} \rangle}_{R_J}$ is in all ideals maximals of the form ${\langle X_{100},X_{1000},X_{1000+{i_1}},\ldots,X_{1000+{i_{98}}} \rangle}_{R_J}$. For any maximal with more inderterminates, the image of this ideal ${\langle X_{100},X_{1000} \rangle}_{R_J}$ through localizations on that maximal is $R_J$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read this carefully enough.

Comment: It is normal.  For this example I had been inspired by understanding the Nagata's example. My target is to find a lemma more general about Notherianity without use the Zorn's lemma. Other posibility is rewrite the proof of I.S. Cohen with an axiom weaker than Axiom Choice.